# How to fix T-SQL error "Incorrect syntax near 'Trebuchet' " when updating HTML column

Tags: html, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update HTML column in SQL Server, but I came across the following error and I don't seem to be able to resolve it. The error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near
>   'Trebuchet'.

I have tried using single and double quotes around the HTML, but none worked.

```
update SC_EmailTemplates set HTML = '<p>&nbsp;</p> <center> <table style="text-align: left;" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="31" height="18"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td width="131" height="18"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="466" height="18"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="31" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td width="131" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="466" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <!--GREEN STRIPE--> <tr> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;" bgcolor="#673090" width="31" height="113"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <!--WHITE TEXT AREA--> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF; text-align: center;" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="131" height="113"><span style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial; color: #673090;">Hello!</span></td> <!--GREEN TEXT AREA--> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; padding-left: 15px;" bgcolor="#673090" height="113"><span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial;">A quick email from Abcd. </span></td> </tr> <!--DOUBLE BORDERS BOTTOM--> <tr> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="31" height="3"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td width="131" height="3"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="border-top: 0px solid #e4e4e4; border-bottom: 0px solid #e4e4e4;" height="3"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="3"><!--CONTENT STARTS HERE--> <br /> <br /> <table width="598" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="15"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="598"><span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Dear [Cr_Clients.NameFirst]</span> <br /> <p>[Message]</p> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <br /> <table style="border-top: 0px solid #e4e4e4; text-align: center; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 586px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td style="border-bottom: 0px solid #e4e4e4; width: 589px;" colspan="3" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 589px;" colspan="3"><a href="mailto:admin@abcd.org.uk?Subject=Unsubscribe Client Reference=[CR_Clients.Client_Ref]">Unsubscribe</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 589px;" colspan="3"> <p>company address 123456798 asdf</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 123.5px;"> <p><a href="https://twitter.com/@abcde1"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" width="60" height="48" /></a></p> <p>&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/@abcd1">Follow us on Twitter</a></p> </td> <td style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 347.5px;"> <p><a href="http://www.abcde.org.uk"><img src="http://abcd.org.uk/assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="Workabout" width="190" height="58" longdesc="http://www.workabout.org.uk" /></a></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> </td> <td style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 118px;"> <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/abcd"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/facebook.png" alt="Find us on Facebook" width="60" height="62" /></a></p> <p><a href="https://twitter.com/@abcde1">Find us on Facebook</a></p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; background: #673090; width: 589px;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </center>'
where ID =57;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using single quotes, you have to double the up (escape them) in your literal string.So for a value like "don't", you would have `'don''t'`.

```
UPDATE SC_EmailTemplates
SET HTML = '<p>&nbsp;</p> <center> <TABLE style="text-align: left;" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="31" height="18"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td width="131" height="18"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="466" height="18"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="31" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td width="131" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="466" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <!--GREEN STRIPE--> <tr> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;" bgcolor="#673090" width="31" height="113"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <!--WHITE TEXT AREA--> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF; text-align: center;" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="131" height="113"><span style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial; color: #673090;">Hello!</span></td> <!--GREEN TEXT AREA--> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #FFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; padding-left: 15px;" bgcolor="#673090" height="113"><span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial;">A quick email from Abcd. </span></td> </tr> <!--DOUBLE BORDERS BOTTOM--> <tr> <td style="border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;" width="31" height="3"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td width="131" height="3"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="border-top: 0px solid #e4e4e4; border-bottom: 0px solid #e4e4e4;" height="3"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="3"><!--CONTENT STARTS HERE--> <br /> <br /> <table width="598" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="15"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> <td style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px;" valign="top" width="598"><span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Dear [Cr_Clients.NameFirst]</span> <br /> <p>[Message]</p> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <br /> <table style="border-top: 0px solid #e4e4e4; text-align: center; font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 586px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td style="border-bottom: 0px solid #e4e4e4; width: 589px;" colspan="3" height="2"> <div style="line-height: 0px; font-size: 1px; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 589px;" colspan="3"><a href="mailto:admin@abcd.org.uk?Subject=Unsubscribe Client Reference=[CR_Clients.Client_Ref]">Unsubscribe</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 589px;" colspan="3"> <p>company address 123456798 asdf</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 123.5px;"> <p><a href="https://twitter.com/@abcde1"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" width="60" height="48" /></a></p> <p>&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/@abcd1">Follow us on Twitter</a></p> </td> <td style="font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 347.5px;"> <p><a href="http://www.abcde.org.uk"><img src="http://abcd.org.uk/assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="Workabout" width="190" height="58" longdesc="http://www.workabout.org.uk" /></a></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> </td> <td style="font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; width: 118px;"> <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/abcd"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/facebook.png" alt="Find us on Facebook" width="60" height="62" /></a></p> <p><a href="https://twitter.com/@abcde1">Find us on Facebook</a></p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-family: ''Trebuchet MS'', Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px; background: #673090; width: 589px;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </center>'
WHERE ID = 57;
```

The reason  this was so hard for you to fix though is because you don't have a single line break in your HTML. Good use of white space and line breaks is paramount in every language. Just like grammar is paramount in spoken language. Without it, all you have is an unreadable mess.

Comment: Thanks very much. I do have properly formatted HTML with new lines but for this question, I thought it's "cleaner" to put it as one line - thanks for the advice. Cheers